# Holiday Gifts for Sound Designers?

Tags: gift, holidays, ideas, wishful-thinking

What holiday gifts will you tell people to get you this year?

I know we all have a microphone that we secretly want but what about something more affordable?

I want The Sound of Star Wars book,  I was able to look at a friends and I would love to have it for myself.

Maybe some rechargeable batteries for my portable recorder?

What is on your wish list? Any cool noise making desk toys, books, or Blu-Rays with SFX related special features?

Comment: The Sounds of Star Wars book is pretty freaking cool, I will say.

Answer (score 4):

I spotted these the other day:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vmeter.net](http://www.vmeter.net/product_images/uploaded_images/vmeter-usb-volume-control-touch-strip-hand.jpg))</sub>

$59

They're pressure sensitive and 8 zone multi-touch too...

Anyone got one? How is it working out?

Comment: That's looking sweet! I don't know it it's caused by syncing issues or youtube or something else, but in the video's on their website (vmeter.net) it seems the device has quite noticable latency: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgbWyc_YcO0&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fvmeter.net%2F&feature=player_embedded

Comment: Whoa! Want one!!!
The syncing, as it is in the video, is indeed worrying, but as all faders and stuff seemed to move pretty much instantaneously, I take it it must be an issue of laggy software-synth. One of the bigger reasons I never work with software-synths...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It's that I have one already, otherwise I would put a Korg Monotron on my list: $60 gets you a little analog synth that's loads of fun and is usable too!
I saw a $20 rebate action on zzsounds (never ordered there because I'm in Europe, but it might be useful for others).

[image]
<sub>(source: [ditverzinjeniet.nl](http://www.ditverzinjeniet.nl/magento/media/upload/image/Stylophone/stylophone_vrijstaand.jpg))</sub>

What I don't have is a Stylophone. Even cheaper, a bit less useful but still another fun little sound generator to play with.

And then you can use them together!

Comment: I love the monotron!

Comment: two new monotron models recently came out. A Dual voice model and one with built in tape delay (emulation). Sweetwater lists these for $10 less than the 'classic'.

Comment: I do love my stylophone.


Comment: @AGZFX Sweet! Both sound cool. There goes my money... (though european shops don't list them yet).

Comment: There is also a Stylophone beatbox. It, too, totally rocks.

Answer (score 2):

Plugins, plugins and more plugins!

Answer (score 2):

Cables and adapters.  Probably the most invaluable tools I have.  Also cash.

Comment: Its the same here

Answer (score 1):

I would totally dig one of these as a gift(obviously on the expensive side though)

http://vaporsky.com/resonant/

Comment: so what sound would you get printed then?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a Google+ chat I've been having, I now want a [RadioShack Mini Audio Amplifier](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062620&CAWELAID=107599029). At $15, it's way cheaper than [Speakerphone](http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html).

Comment: Not as versatile though ;-) I don't know if this is purely an economic question for you or a matter of philosophy, but I myself prefer hardware over plugins as far as possible, and that includes micing up speakers and amplifiers rather than Speakerphone it :-)

Comment: As I don't have Speakerphone, or $150 I can throw at it, I can't attest to it's versatility. ;-) This just seems to fit the bill and be a useful tool in general. In my current setup a plug-in is a huge time-saver, but I'm hoping to change that very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Designer Armani or Dolce & Gabbana Ear Muffs.

Answer (score 0):

For the holidays I got rechargeable batteries and a cool charger that charges, tests, and refreshes the batteries, The Sounds of Star Wars, and a giftcard to Amazon with which I bought myself a Korg Monotron that I am excitedly awaiting to arrive!!